# Getting Face From The Picture

Tags: android, image, image-processing, face-recognition

Here is what i have done till now.

1. I have launched the camera from my application
2. I have taken a photo
3. I have used the face detection technique to paint a square green window in the face region

Now I am wondering, how will i extract the exact face using face detection?

I have gone through a number of questions over stack overflow related to this problem, unfortunately, the solutions are not accurate enough.

I mean, I have seen solutions like performing cropping based on circular window, but **I somehow need to get the exact face extracted from the image**. Is it possible? How? Whats the best possible solution available to do this?  Any code snippets would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to extract the face itself or a bounding box around the face?

Comment: sir actually i did face detection for this purpose i mean to help the face extraction process. My main task or the end task is to get the face extracted in form of bitmap from the picture up to maximum accuracy.

Comment: OK, I mean - do you want to extract the face as a bounding box or do you need to extract a tight contour that surrounds the face?

Comment: sir i just want to extract face out of the picture.Just the face.

Comment: Then you can find contours:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

After some post processing, perhaps you could get a tight contour surrounding the face.